# how will i know the size of user control?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, size

How will I know the size of user control at run time?

I have a form, and I wanted to host my usercontrol on that form, and I wanted
to know  my user control size at run time to fix my webform size according to 
my user control size, so that scroll should not appear while opening the form.

How can I do that?

(actually there are multiple Usercontrols, and I am hosting a user control at run time
according to a condition.)

Answer (score 1):

You can *expose* a `.Size` property that would contain the height/width of user control. While rendering the control, you read the `.Size` and process accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `ActualWidth / ActualHeight`?

Also you should be able to set the `ScrollBar` policy to `Auto` so that it will only appear if needed.